# Attribute error in parsing a file with python

Tags: python, parsing, iterator, attributes

I want to create a program that reads a file and gets the percentages that people scored on a test. I used the following code. Then next() part i used to skip the lines that do not contain useful information. However, i keep getting this error:

lines.next()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'

```
def process_line(percent):
number = int(percent/10);
if number == 10:
    ui.raise_bar(9)
else: 
    ui.raise_bar(number)



source = open('statistics1.txt', 'r');
lines = source.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if line[0] == '-' or line[0] == '=' or line[0] == 'I':
        lines.next()
    else:
        process_line(line[3])
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very precise:  'lines' is a list of strings and doesn't know about 'next'.  It's not an iterator or so.  You could use a simple `continue` instead, then it goes on with the next iteration.  Or even better, rewrite the condition:

```
for line in lines:
    if line[0] not in '-=I':
        process_line(line[3])
```

By the way, you don't need to read the entire file upfront,

```
source = open('statistics1.txt')
for line in source:
    ....
```

would do the same thing and read each line as it's processed.
EDIT:  And please note that `line[3]` gives you the third character in the string, which is probably not what you want.  Maybe you want something like `line.split()[3]` instead.